# Initialization of Uri type

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am trying to initialize array of Uri.

Can anyone tell me how to initialize array of type Uri in c#?

I have tried initializing like string but it shows some error.

Comment: Like this? `Uri[] array = new Uri[]{...};`

Comment: `Uri[] array = new Uri[] { new Uri("..."), new Uri("...") };`

Answer (score 2):

List is another option to use URI. Here is the example to create a list of type Uri, May this will help you.

```
List<Uri> listUri = new List<Uri>();

  listUri.Add(new Uri(""));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an array then

```
Uri UriArray=new Uri[]{new Uri("/MainPage.xaml",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)};
```

else, You Can use List

```
List<Uri> uriList=new List<Uri>();
uriList.Add(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml",UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```